# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.dll Additional information: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#

i am trying to call webservice to createfolder in sharepoint .

I've added the service reference for particular wsdl in my application, when i run my application it hitting the **base.url** in following code

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.0.30319.34209")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="DwsSoap", Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/")]
    public partial class Dws : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback CreateDwsOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback DeleteDwsOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback GetDwsMetaDataOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback GetDwsDataOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback UpdateDwsDataOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback RemoveDwsUserOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback RenameDwsOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback FindDwsDocOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback CanCreateDwsUrlOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback CreateFolderOperationCompleted;

        private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback DeleteFolderOperationCompleted;

        private bool useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly;

        /// <remarks/>
        public Dws() {
            this.Url = global::webservice.Properties.Settings.Default.webservice_FolderReference_Dws;
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }

        public new string Url {
            get {
                return base.Url;
            }
            set {
                if ((((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(base.Url) == true) 
                            && (this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly == false)) 
                            && (this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(value) == false))) {
                    base.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                }
                base.Url = value;// **hitting here**
            }
        }
```

kindly anyone help me out...

Comment: The implication is you're setting it to `null`, which isn't allowed.  Don't set it to `null`?

Comment: where should i change?

Comment: Looking at it closer, this is set from your settings.  Ensure your `webservice_FolderReference_Dws` setting has a value.

Comment: you are correct webservice.Properties.Settings.Default.webservice_FolderReference_Dws; has null value may i know how do change the value?

Comment: is it possible to change the settings value as you told?

Comment: Yes, you can either change the default value or set it at runtime - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) for more detail.